# loadLayout() is not working?

Tags: magento-1.8, layout-update

here is my config file..   (Lalit/Consultation/etc/config.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lalit_Consultation>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Lalit_Consultation>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <consultation>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Lalit_Consultation</module>
                    <frontName>online-consultation</frontName>
                </args>
            </consultation>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <consultation>
                    <file>consulation.xml</file>
                </consultation>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <consultation>
                <class>Lalit_Consultation_Block</class>
            </consultation>

        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <consultation>
                <class>Lalit_Consultation_Helper</class>
            </consultation>
        </helpers>
    </global>

</config>
```

working fine! here's controller file (Lalit/Consultation/controllers/IndexController.php)

```
<?php
class Lalit_Consultation_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
    public function indexAction(){

       Mage::log('im in controller');
        $this->loadLayout();
        Zend_Debug::dump($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());

        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

}

here's block file   (Lalit/Consultation/Block/Consultation.php)

```
<?php
class Lalit_Consultation_Block_Consultation extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{
    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    }
}
```

here's layout file (app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/consultation.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <consultation_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="consultation/consultation" name="consultation" template="consultation/consultation.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </consultation_index_index>

</layout>
```

Helper file in (app/design/frontend/base/default/templates/consultation/Helper/Data.php)

```
<?php
class Lalit_Consultation_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{

}
```

template file in (app/design/frontend/base/default/templates/consultation/consultation.phtml)

```
<h2><?php echo $this->__('this is testing') ?></h2>
```

Here's my output
[image]

Comment: I have updated my answer you can refer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what is the exact issue over there but you can hack by following code in your `indexAction()`

```
    $this->loadLayout();

    $root = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('root');
    $template = "page/1column.phtml";
    $root->setTemplate($template);

    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('consultation/consultation');
    $block->setTemplate("consultation/consultation.phtml");
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);

    $this->renderLayout();
```

And also I doubt that Your layout File name is different from config

In your config layout file name is `consulation.xml` and in your layout folder file name is `consultation.xml`

Comment: i mistyped file name in layout file as you mention    @murtuza thanks  it's worked for me

Comment: You are always welcome @lalitmohan :)

Comment: check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/191252/magento-2-1-6-checkout-issues-show-no-payment-method also

Answer (score 0):

I found many typo error in your code

Check the **frontname** you had defined.

> config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lalit_Consultation>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Lalit_Consultation>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <consultation>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Lalit_Consultation</module>
                    <frontName>consultation</frontName>
                </args>
            </consultation>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <consultation>
                    <file>consulation.xml</file>
                </consultation>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <consultation>
                <class>Lalit_Consultation_Block</class>
            </consultation>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <consultation>
                <class>Lalit_Consultation_Helper</class>
            </consultation>
        </helpers>
    </global>
</config>
```

> layout/consulation.xml

Make sure you have same name of your xml which you have defined in your config.xml. I found it different in your code posted in question.

Also change `templates` to `template`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <consultation_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="consultation/consultation" name="consultation" template="consultation/consultation.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </consultation_index_index>
</layout>
```

You need to call your url `http://example.com/consultation/`

Comment: I tried you answer but didn't work

Comment: are you calling url by `http://example.com/consultation/index/index`

Comment: no just http://mage.local/consultation/

Comment: and have you changed the frontname ? in your config.xml and done all changes mentioned in the answer?

Comment: Yes I changed as you mentioned

Comment: Did it worked for you? You can check the module I have created for you. https://github.com/priyankbro/m1frontlayout/

Answer (score 0):

**app/code/local/Lalit/Consultation/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lalit_Consultation>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Lalit_Consultation>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <consultation>
                <class>Lalit_Consultation_Block</class>
            </consultation>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <consultation>
                <class>Lalit_Consultation_Helper</class>
            </consultation>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <consultation>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Lalit_Consultation</module>
                    <frontName>online-consultation</frontName>
                </args>
            </consultation>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <consultation>
                    <file>consultation.xml</file>
                </consultation>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Lalit/Consultation/controllers/IndexController.php**

```
<?php
class Lalit_Consultation_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {    
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

**app/design/frontend/{name space}/{your theme}/layout/consultation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <consultation_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action> //1column.phtml for exemple
            <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="consultation"><title>Consultation</title></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="consultation" as="consult" template="consultation/consultation.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </consultation_index_index>
</layout>
```

**app/design/frontend/{name space}/{your theme}/templates/consultation/consultation.phtml**

```
<h2><?php echo $this->__('Welcome') ?></h2>
```

**app/code/local/Lalit/Consultation/Helper/Data.php**

```
<?php

class Lalit_Consultation_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

Comment: I didn't mention helper file Data.php but i already created as you answer

Comment: Yes, please try my answer i didn't test it but it should work

Comment: bad luck nothing changed , i updated my question to show output

Comment: what theme are you using ? and where you want to display your phtml ?

Comment: i'm doing it on Magento default theme right now . you can see on my updated question screenshot.

Comment: Have you tried the solution ? and  `app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/consultation.xml`, `app/design/frontend/default/default/templates/consultation/consultation.phtml` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64881/discussion-between-prince-and-lalit-mohan).